# Concatenate images with same size using vstack

Tags: opencv, design-patterns

I'm using vstack to concat 2 images but after concatenation, I have a line between the 2 images. I want to know if there is a proper way to remove that line or another way to create a seamless repeat pattern image by concatenation.

Comment: Show some code, show an image, then we can help.

Answer (score -1):

```
import cv2
[concat image][1]import numpy as np

im1 = cv2.imread('test1.jpeg')
y=0
x=0
h=2000
w=2000
im1 = im1[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

[concat_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnJpk.jpg)

```
im_v = cv2.vconcat([im1, im1, im1])
im_v2 = cv2.hconcat([im_v,im_v, im_v])
cv2.imwrite('opencv_vconcat.png', im_v2)
```